# Multiple row subquery MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need help with this query I don't know how I can do a sub-queries but what I am trying to do is the following:

`Date`, `HNO`, `IDNAM`, `IDFNAM`, `Pre weight`, `post weight`, `Calculation pre weight - post weight`

The problem I have got is this is how the data is stored in the table for the weight column, see sample data below from database table, There is a row for pre, then another row for post in the weight same column

> ```
> 28/04/2017,D123456,BLOGGS,Joe,HOSP HD,79.8,POST
> 28/04/2017,D123456,BLOGGS,Joe,HOSP HD,80.4,PRE
> 26/04/2017,D123456,BLOGGS,Joe,HOSP HD,79.2,POST
> 26/04/2017,D123456,BLOGGS,Joe,HOSP HD,80.2,PRE
> 21/04/2017,D123456,BLOGGS,Joe,HOSP HD,78.6,POST
> 21/04/2017,D123456,BLOGGS,Joe,HOSP HD,82.8,PRE
> ```

I want to achieve this result set below

> ```
> 28/04/2017|D123456|BLOGGS|Joe|HOSP HD|80.4 Pre|79.8 Post|calculation using alias
> 26/04/2017|D123456|BLOGGS|Joe|HOSP HD|80.2 Pre|79.2 Post|calculation using alias
> 21/04/2017|D123456|BLOGGS|Joe|HOSP HD|82.8 Pre|78.6 Post|calculation
> ```

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(D1.HRDATE, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Date, IDHNO, IDNAM, IDFNAM,IDSTS,
(SELECT HRWGT FROM p_dialysis D2 WHERE D2.oid = D1.oid AND HRPrePost LIKE 'pre' AND HRWGT is not null) AS Pre,
(SELECT HRWGT FROM p_dialysis D3 WHERE D3.oid = D1.oid AND HRPrePost LIKE 'post' AND HRWGT is not null) AS Post,
(SELECT (SELECT Pre) - (SELECT Post)) AS Total FROM p_dialysis D1
    LEFT JOIN p_person ON D1.fk_oid = p_person.oid WHERE D1.HRDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') AND IDHNO LIKE 'D000000%' AND D1.HRWGT > 0
```

The code above produces this result

> ```
> 28/04/2017    D123456 BLOGGS  Joe HOSP HD NULL    79.8    
> 28/04/2017    D123456 BLOGGS  Joe HOSP HD 80.4    NULL    
> 26/04/2017    D123456 BLOGGS  Joe HOSP HD NULL    79.2    
> 26/04/2017    D123456 BLOGGS  Joe HOSP HD 80.2    NULL        
> 21/04/2017    D123456 BLOGGS  Joe HOSP HD NULL    78.6    
> 21/04/2017    D123456 BLOGGS  Joe HOSP HD 82.8    NULL
> ```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on your total table schema, but to get your result you can join your table on itself as the sub query to get the result

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pre.HRDATE, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Date, pre.IDHNO, pre.IDNAM, pre.IDFNAM, pre.IDSTS,  CONCAT(pre.HRPrePost, ' ' ,pre.HRWGT), CONCAT(pst.HRPrePost,' ' ,pst.HRWGT)
FROM your_table pre
    INNER JOIN(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(HRDATE, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Date, IDHNO, IDNAM, IDFNAM, IDSTS, HRPrePost, HRWGT
    FROM your_table 
        WHERE HRPrePost = 'POST'
) pst
ON pst.`Date` = DATE_FORMAT(pre.HRDATE, '%d/%m/%Y') AND pre.IDHNO = pst.IDHNO

WHERE pre.HRPrePost = 'PRE'
```